When is $M\left(A\right)\otimes M\left(B\right)$ isomorphic to $M\left(A\otimes B\right)$
Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two $C^*$-algebras. Let $M\left(A\right)$ and $M\left(B\right)$ be the multiplier algebras respectively. Here $\otimes$ means the maximal $C^*$-tensor product.
A standard verification shows that $M\left(M_n\otimes K\right)$ is isomorphic $M\left(M_n\right)\otimes M\left(K\right)$, since they both are isomorphic to $B\left(l^2\right)$, where $l^2$ is a separable Hilbert space and $K$ is the compact operators algebra.
We can see $M\left(A\right)\otimes M\left(B\right)$ is isomorphic to $M\left(A\otimes B\right)$ in the previous statement. Unfortunately, The isomorphism does not hold in general.
I would like to know the following question : Is $M\left(M_n\left(A\right)\right)$ isomorphic to $M_n\left(M\left(A\right)\right)$?

Relevant? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/239720/multiplier-algebra-of-a-otimes-mathcalk

@ThusleGadelankz Thank you for your reference. However, what I would like to know is different from it. I mean, here we request one of two $C^*$-algebra is a simple matrix algebra, which is nuclear unital and finite dimensional.

Yes, this is true. The multiplier algebra of $A$ is (either by definition or by a theorem) the idealizer $I_{B(H)}(A)$ of $A$ in a faithful non-degenerate representation $A \to B(H)$. So, let $\pi: A \to B(H)$ be a faithful non-degenerate representation. Then,
$$1_{M_n} \otimes \pi: M_n(A) \to M_n(B(H)) = B(H^{\oplus n})$$
is a faithful non-degenerate representation of $M_n(A)$. It is then an easy calculation to show that,
$$M(M_n(A)) = I_{B(H^{\oplus n})}(M_n(A)) = M_n(I_{B(H)}(A)) = M_n(M(A))$$

What is the relation between the faithful non-degenerate representation and universal representation? I mean the multiplier algebra $M\left(A\right)$ is the idealizer of $A$ in $A^{"}$, where $A^{"}$ is the strong completion of $A$ with respect to the universal representation. Universal representation is actually a faithful non-degenerate representation. Thank you very much for your answer.

@HaoWang The universal representation is certainly a faithful non-degenerate representation, but in general is not going to be the only one. It is a theorem that $M(A)$ is isomorphic to the idealizer of $A$ in any faithful non-degenerate representation (see here), not just restricted to the universal representation.

Thank you for your information. I may get some idea in the representation

First, we claim the following statement.
Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra and $\pi: A\to B\left(H\right)$ be a non-degenerate representation. Then there is a unique $\pi^{"}: A^{"}\to \pi\left(A\right)^{"}$ such that $\pi^{"}|_{A}=\pi$ and it is weak-weak continuous, that is, if $\{x_\lambda\}$ is a weak convergent net in the von Neumann algebra $Aˆ{"}$ then $\{\pi^{"}\left(x_\lambda\right)\}$ is a weak convergent net in $B\left(H\right)$.
proof: We assume that $\left(\pi,H\right)$ is cyclic with cyclic vector $\xi$ with $\Vert\xi\Vert=1$. Then $\phi\left(a\right)=\langle\pi\left(a\right)\xi,\xi\rangle$ is a state, and hence $\left(\pi,H\right)$ is unitary equivalent to $\left(\pi_\phi,H_\phi\right)$, which is the cyclic representation induced by the state $\phi$. Without loss of generality, we assume that $\left(\pi,H\right)=\left(\pi_\phi,H_\phi\right)$. Let $p_\phi$ be the projection of $H_U$ onto $H_\phi$, where $\left(\pi_U,H_U\right)$ is the universal representation of $A$. Then $p_\phi\pi_U\left(a\right)=\pi_U\left(a\right)=\pi_U\left(a\right)$ for all $a\in A$. Thus $\pi_\phi\in A^{'}$. It is clear that the map $x\mapsto p_\phi x$ is weak-weak continuous from $A^{"}$ into $\pi\left(A\right)^{"}$.
In general, it is necessary to notice that a non-degenerate representation could be written as the direct sum of cyclic representations.
Using previous statement, if $\pi: A\to B\left(H\right)$ is a faithful non-generate representation, then $\pi\left(A\right)^{"}$ is isomorphic to the envelop von Neumann algebra $A^{"}$. Therefore $ID\left(\pi\left(A\right)\right)$ is isomorphic to the multiplier algebra $M\left(A\right)$.
In the rest, we just apply the previous answer given by  David Gao.

Here we just complete the statement about multiplier algebra in the answer given by David Gao

The first statement, that there is a unique normal $\ast$-homomorphism from $A^{\ast\ast}$ to $\pi(A)’’$ that restricts to identity on $A$, is certainly correct. But the final statement, that if $\pi: A \to B(H)$ is faithful non-degenerate, then $A^{\ast\ast}$ is isomorphic to $\pi(A)’’$, is false. Say, the identity representation $\pi$ of $A = B(H)$ on $H$ is faithful non-degenerate, and $\pi(A)’’ = B(H)$, but the universal enveloping von Neumann algebra $A^{\ast\ast} = B(H)^{\ast\ast}$ is far larger than $B(H)$ (when $H$ is infinite-dimensional).

The statement I said about multiplier algebras is correct, but the proof that the idealizer does not depend on the choice of the faithful non-degenerate representation $\pi$ is far more complicated than this. The Wikipedia article on multiplier algebras provides the proof modulo a lemma. You can definitely find the proof for this lemma in some of the textbooks on $C^\ast$-algebras, though I will admit I can’t remember which. Probably Dixmier’s book? I’m not entirely sure.

(By the way, the reason the unique map $A^{\ast\ast} \to \pi(A)’’$ can fail to be an isomorphism is because, while it is always surjective, it can fail be injective. Its restriction to $A$ is certainly injective, but that doesn’t mean the entire map is injective.)

Thank you very much for your comment. I will check it again.
